# Excel To DataTable - Adds an additional column F1

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm loading the excel records to a datatable. When this table is bound to a gridview, I see an additional column 'F1' and also an additional row with empty data. How can I prevent this.

For example, the excel sheet has these records:

```
Name L1 L2    
abc   2 4
def   3 3
```

When bound to grid view, I see as an additional column(F1) and a row(3)

```
S.No Name L1 L2 F1    
1     abc  2  4
2     def  3  3
3
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">    
 <columns>    
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">    
    <ItemTemplate>    
      <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1%>    
    </ItemTemplate>    
   </asp:TemplateField>    
 </columns>    
</asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();    
DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);    
conn.Open();     
 dtExcel = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,null);    
 string qry = "select * from [Sheet1$]";    
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry,conn);    
 da.Fill(dt);    
 conn.Close();    
 gv.DataSource=dt;    
 gv.DataBind();
```

Would just deleting the last column be a good approach.Why is it coming in the first place.
Another option would be deleting the column with name 'F1' in the DataTable, but what if that may also be a name of one of the original columns like L1, L2, ....

Answer (score 1):

Simply update your `select` statement with columns you require and make sure they are available in the Excel file:

```
 string qry = "select [L1], [L2] from [Sheet1$]";
```

**Update for Dynamic Query**

```
  //if you have muliple condition then use StringBuilder class 
   //for making column list

        string strColumns=string.Empty;
        if(CoditionForL1)
        {
            strColumns =strColumns+ "[L1] ,";
        }

        if (ConditionForL2)
        {
            strColumns = strColumns + "[L2],";
        }

   string qry = "select "+(strColumns= strColumns.TrimEnd(','))+" from [Sheet1$]";
```

Comment: What if the columns are dynamic

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic columns? Do you mapping columns with any variable or textbox?

Comment: The no. of columns cant be determined in this case and hence did not hardcode in the aspx.The cols, L1, L2....n can increase.

Comment: create your `select` statement dynamic. Could you please share conditon? is it in any if - else

Comment: There is no if else condition. Just the way as in question.

Comment: Thank you but not an option. The names and the no. of columns is always unknown. They also can vary from sheet to sheet and hence your answer is not possible for my case unfortunately. For now, I am just checking the column index and name and deleting it

Comment: how you are getting the column names ?